# Standard 12 Volt DC fan for PC: how much AC ripple can support? Does ripple increase noise?

Tags: power-supply, dc, capacitance, fan, ripple

I want to know which is the mechanical effect to run a DC 12V brushless common fan with a very basic and poor power supply (just a diode plus a low value capacitor, no regulation at all). In principle,  which are the effects of the AC ripple? If I increase capacitance (so decrease AC ripple) should the DC fan run "better", faster and make lower acustical noise? 
Can high AC ripple decrease fan life also?

Comment: Does a bycycle run smoother on round wheels or square wheels?

Comment: Ripply voltage is probably worse than smooth, but it may not be too much worse. Try it, you might be pleasantly surprised.

Answer (score 1):

These days, PC fans use 4-wire PWM connection. But the older 2 and 3-wire fans are [controlled](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/how-to-control-fan-speed.html) by PWMing their power supply at a low frequency. This is 100% ripple. Thus, it should work in your application.

I'm not sure about using a single diode though, the frequency maybe low enough for it to vibrate, you'll have to try it I guess...

Comment: Low PWM frequencies, as in single or double digit Hz, create audible noise in 12V fans, IME. PWMing them at 25 kHz is a natural thing to do, as that means you can use parts of the same logic as when PWMing 4 wire fans, which are nominally controlled at ~25 kHz. But anyway, to try and see is the only answer to the OP's question, because fans differ and ripples differ.